# How to mock a method within an action method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq

I want to mock (with `MOQ`) the method `CheckCredentials` which is part of the `LoginManager` class.

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
            {
                if (lm.CheckCredentials(username, password) != 0)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

Testmethod

```
public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Mock<LoginManager> mock = new Mock<LoginManager>();

        mock.Setup(x => x.CheckCredentials("", "")).Returns(0); 

        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();

        RedirectToRouteResult ar = homeController.Login("", "") as RedirectToRouteResult;
        ...
    }
```

Now my problem is that I don't really now how to correctly mock that method. I have seen YT videos where the mock objects are passed as parameters but isn't that quite bad if I have to change the parameters of a method just to be able to create a unit test? Is that the only way to do it or are there other possibilities?

Comment: What is `lm` instance of your `LoginManager`? What is it scope and how is it instantiated? Do you somehow pass it into your controller constructor or public property, or is it tightly coupled with controller code? Testable code should be written in a special way, for example you have to pass all external dependencies to the class using some dependency injection framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract an interface for your LoginManager class.

```
public interface ILoginManager
{
    int CheckCredentials(string userName, string password);
}

public class LoginManager : ILoginManager
{
    public int CheckCredentials(string userName, string password)
    {
        // your existing implementation.
    }
}
```

And inject an implementation of `ILoginManager` to your controller via constructor injection.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ILoginManager loginManager;
    public HomeController(ILoginManager loginManager)
    {
        this.loginManager = loginManager;
    }
    public ActionResult Login(string userName,string password)
    {
        if (loginManager.CheckCredentials(username, password) != 0)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

and in your test, create a mocked version of the ILoginManager and mock the behavior using `SetUp` method.

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ILoginManager>();

    mock.Setup(x => x.CheckCredentials("", "")).Returns(0);

    var homeController = new HomeController(mock.Object);

    var ar = homeController.ReportScore("") as RedirectToRouteResult;

    //TO DO : Assert something

}
```